# C++ statement is ignored in function

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

I have this test program and it seems like some statements inside a function (`gcd()`) are ignored. The `std::cout` statement seems to be ignored since nothing is printed to the screen with that statement. The `if` statement seems to be ignored because `a` and `b` were less than zero and `b` was positive whether that `if` statement was there or not (`a` and `b` remained the same).

I can't figure out why. Why are the two statements marked (with comment) are ignored?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

template <typename T> T gcd(T a, T b)
{
    T remainder{a % b};
    while (remainder != 0)
    {
        a = b;
        b = remainder;
        std::cout << remainder << '\n'; // ignored
        remainder = a % b;
    }
    if (a < 0 && b < 0) b *= -1; // ignored
    return b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << '\n' <<
                     "Invalid number of argument(s)\n" <<
                     '\n' <<
                     "Usage: [number] [number]\n" <<
                     '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int a{0}, b{0};
    try
    {
        a = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int{argv[1]};
        b = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int{argv[2]};
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << '\n' <<
                     "Invalid argument(s) or numbers too large/small\n" <<
                     '\n' <<
                     "Usage: [number] [number]\n" <<
                     '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    const boost::multiprecision::cpp_int vgcd = gcd(a, b); // call to gcd()
    std::cout << '\n' <<
                 "GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) test program using Euclid's algorithm (iterative)\n" <<
                 '\n' <<
                 "GCD(a, 0) = a\n" <<
                 "GCD(a, b) = GCD(b, a % b)\n" <<
                 '\n' <<
                 "GCD = " << vgcd << "      Simplified fraction: " << a / vgcd << " / " << b / vgcd << '\n' <<
                 '\n';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with the debugger, inspecting condition variables on the way?

Comment: Let's tackle the second "ignored" first. What are the values of `a` and `b` prior to the test? Are you sure your template overload of `gcd` is even called? (Overload resolution favours non-template functions over template ones.)

Comment: @Bathsheba `a` was `-48` and `b` was `-18` every time for all the tests I did.

Comment: @peterchen No, I haven't. I'm on Linux and not really familiar with GDB (at least inspecting variables).

Comment: Can you strip the boost out, replacing with built-in types? (for the purpose of diagnosis).

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually, I stripped out built-in types replacing it with `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int`. The return value of `gcd()` was negative then. Now it is positive.

Comment: @Bathsheba As for the template overloads isn't `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` deduced as the type?

Comment: What values are you supplying for `a` and `b`?   If they are both positive, and `b` is a factor of `a`, then the two statements will have no apparent effect.

Comment: @peterchen you should probably avoid using the term "condition variable" unless you mean something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: @6EQUJ5 _"I'm on Linux and not really familiar with GDB"_ this seems like a good time to learn then, no? You don't even need to inspect any variables, just step through and see which functions get called. Hint: it's far more likely that the statement isn't run, rather than the compiler "ignoring" it. The compiler knows C++ a lot better than you do.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I will. Huh, the command line arguments are simple to do the essential things...

Comment: So pass the command-line arguments to the `run` command in GDB, or change your program to be non-interactive. Compile with `-g` then open the executable in gdb, then `break 46`, `run -48 -18` (or whatever numbers you want to pass), `step` ... notice what happened.

Comment: Wow, it calls the boost version of gcd()...

Comment: @JonathanWakely Actually, I can't really tell the difference between `gcd()` and `::gcd()`. A ton of boost code which I think is the constructor code. How can I see the name (return val, params, etc) of the function being called?

Comment: When you step into the called function GDB prints its name, and args, and source location: `boost::multiprecision::gcd<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >
 > (arg=..., a=...) at /usr/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/default_ops.hpp:2122` ... do you think that's your function or not? View the arguments with `print arg` and `print a`. Find a tutorial on GDB.

Comment: And when stepping into your function, it shows: `gcd<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0u, 0u, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type)1, (boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type)0, std::allocator<unsigned long
long> >, (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)1> > (a=..., b=...) at test.cc:6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't actually call your `gcd`. `boost::multiprecision` provides [its own `gcd` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/number.html#boost_multiprecision.ref.number.integer_functions), which is a better match than your template and picked up by ADL in your `gcd(a, b)`.

Suppress ADL with `::gcd(a, b)` or `(gcd)(a, b)` and you'll see your function template get called.

Comment: That was my initial hunch. Have an upvote! I'm starting to doubt my explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good explanation. I was wondering why the `cout` statement wouldn't execute.